# How to change text with Bootstrap toggle switch

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap toggle switch with a monthly or annual option like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
       jQuery("#price").val(this.value);
    }); 
});
</script>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<ul class="plan plan2">
<li class="plan-name">Professional</li>
<h4 class="plan-benefit"><input type="text" id="price" value="$99/mo"><br/>
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-primary active"><input type="radio" value="$99/mo" checked> Monthly</label><label class="btn btn-primary"><input type="radio" value="$299/mo"> Annual</label>
</div>
```

How can I change the price like:
If Monthly = $99 and If Annual = $299

Comment: *this is for Wordpress, hence jQuery instead of $

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, The above works fine. You only missed thhe `name` attribute which only allow one radio to be checked at a time. Your radio tags should look like this:

```
<label class="btn btn-primary active">
   <input type="radio" value="$99/mo" name="rd1" checked> Monthly
</label>

 <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" value="$299/mo" name="rd1"> Annual
 </label>
```

Comment: It works by itself with <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> but it wouldn't work inside my Wordpress page..

Comment: Do inspect element in Chrome and view the console area to see what the errors are.